# Constant pointer modified in function

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I tried compiling this code being absolutely sure it won't compile since I try to modify the address to a const pointer (int p[100]), but the code compiled and run perfectly. Can anyone explain to me why this worked?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int bar1(int *p){ cout << p << " "; p++; cout << p << "\n"; return 0; }
int bar2(int p[100]){ cout << p << " "; p++; cout << p; return 0; }

int arr1[100];
int arr2[100];

int main(){
    bar1(arr1);
    bar2(arr2);
}
```

I compiled this in Visual Studio 2013 the output was:

3f320 3f324

3f4B0 3f4B4

Comment: I see no `const`.

Comment: Call `bar1(arr1)` and `bar2(arr2)` a second time and you'll see that your functions don't modify anything.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to modify the address to a `const` pointer (`int p[100]`)

That's not a `const` pointer. As a function parameter, it's equivalent to `int * p`.

A `const` pointer looks like `int * const p`, and your code will give the expected compile error if you use that.